# Download button to save something that's already online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, download

I'm doing a download form. I want to make the submit button download something that's already online, and not only open that something that you can save while on it. I want the download to start when you click the button basically.

This is what I have right now:

```
<form method="get" action="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw4jL.png">
     <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to force a download if you control the server by adding the header `Content-Disposition: attachment`. However, from the client (JavaScript or HTML) the only way to force a remote URL to be downloaded is using [the `<a download>` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Using_the_download_attribute_to_save_a_canvas_as_a_PNG). You can't do it directly as a `<form>`'s native action.

You could wrap the button in a `download` link, and remove its `type="submit"` (and probably the `<form>` too in this case):

```html
<a download href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw4jL.png"><input  value="Download" /></a>
```

Or you could have an invisible link triggered instead of submitting the form to a server:

```html
<form onsubmit="downloadLink.click(); return false;">
  <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
  <a download href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw4jL.png" id="downloadLink"></a>
</form>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the catch -- my prose described removing `type="submit"`, but I seem to have missed that in my code snippet. Fixed that now.

Comment: But why would wrapping a button be a good idea? Just style the link... And inline event handlers could be reasons for downvoting by sticklers - of which there are plenty at SO